# What ROS distribution with OpenCV 4

Tags: ros-melodic, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am **completely** new with ROS, but I want to start using ROS and integrate it with OpenCV 4 (C++/python). The simple approach I am thinking is to create a node reading from a camera and creating another node to process it (I have doubts in connection with creating two nodes and a topic, or creating a service, ..).

At least, I want OpenCV 4 capabilities to process the frames in one node (e.g. face detection, apply pre-trained deep learning models available in OpenCV, among others - but starting with a very simple processing algorithm).

My question is: What ROS distribution is necessary/recommended for OpenCV 4 compatibility? I am reading this (http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions) but only appears OpenCV 3.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/332950/what-ros-distribution-with-opencv-4/) by [albertofernandez](https://answers.ros.org/users/45607/albertofernandez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-09-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS uses the system opencv library, so for now you are bound to opencv 3.2.0. You can find packages list for Ubuntu [on this page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/allpackages)

If you want a newer opencv version you can install it by yourself but you have to adapt CMakeLists.txt to force it to use a specific version.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2019-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2